# Every rational Polynomial is a product of the content and a primitive Polynomial

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

If $f\in \mathbb{Q}[X]\setminus \{0\}$ then $\, f=cont(f)\cdot f_1$ with $f_1 \in \mathbb{Z}[X]$ being a primitive Polynomial.

Why is that the case?

Comment: See [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_part_and_content).

Comment: I believe you want $f(x)\in \mathbb{Z}[x]$, not $\mathbb{Q}[x]$. In that case, you can just factor out the gcd of the coefficients.